# Touchpad/Mouse/Wifi does not function in 12.04/14.04/15.04 but works on 12.10

Tags: 14.04, 12.10, 15.04, mouse, touchpad

I recently got a new ssd for a netbook I had sitting around and decided to put ubuntu on it. After some googling of the make model of the net book (ACER AO 756-2899) the version that kept showing up was 12.10 but I know it's a little out of date. So i tried it anyway. The installation went smoothly, touchpad, wifi, usb mouse worked perfectly.

But I was cautioned that 12.10 would not have security updates and should update to a newer version like 14.04 LTS. So I did, i loaded up a USB flash drive and installed 14.04 erasing the new SSD and freshly installed 14.04. During the process the wifi worked, the touchpad worked and the usb mouse worked. AFTER installation though, when it asked to restart. That's when things start to. I restarted, it booted up to the ubuntu desktop. Touchpad is unresponsive, usb mouse is powered but unresponsive. Wifi is now disconnected.

I manually tried to reach the network settings but there are no networks to connect to to see if i can update anything. I searched online about the touchpad issues with ubuntu and it looks like others have had the same issue but I tried repeating the same steps. Go into the terminal tried to activate the touchpad during the session but it would say the file was not found. Or it can't update the touchpad because i don't have internet.

At this point, i thought maybe something went wrong with the install. I formatted the harddrive and reinstalled 14.04. same issue. So I downloaded 15.04, same issue. Ok let's try 12.04, same issue. Then I re-download 12.10 - it works great, everything is stable. But i am worried about security.

My question is... should i keep 12.10 with some software that could protect me? Or should I get back into 14.04 and try to fix it?

Thank you so much,

-Wing

Edit: [ubuntu14.04 dmesg](http://pastebin.com/q52TSJq7)

Comment: Keeping 12.10 with some software to protect you is not going to work. Are you able to post the output of `dmesg` here? You can save it to a file and paste it on pastebin: `dmesg > dmesg.log`

Comment: should i be doing this after i install 14.04 again? Or can i give the information while i am still in 12.10, @daltonfury42

Comment: Whhat is your network controller? You will find it by running `lspci`. Run it on 12.04

Comment: @daltonfury42 03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)

Comment: I can do nothing about wifi. Someone may help if you post the dmesg logs from Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @daltonfury42 meaning when i go back into 14,04 i post the dmesg log from the terminal? It'll be hard since i can't use a mouse to copy and paste or get on the internet from there.  Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: You could install 14.04 alongside 12.10(working). The command will create a file called dmesg.log in your 14.04 installation. You can post it from your working installation.

Comment: I got the dmseg but i can't paste it in the text box. Too many characters. @daltonfury42

Comment: Paste it in pastebin and add the link to the question

Comment: @daltonfury42 ok i added it.

Comment: @daltonfury42 I ended up installing Linux Mint and everything worked from a fresh install. Thanks for trying to help me.